# JS to combat cached page

Tags: javascript, caching

I need a quick js code to reload the page if it is cached.  I need this too show changes to the page without having to refresh the page to make the changes appear.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can [force a non-cached reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload) in this way:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```